# Has the WHO or any individual countries released COVID-19 statistics divided on basis of sex?

Tags: international, covid-19, statistics, who

In February 2019, the U.S.A released HIV statistics based on sex:

[image]

Have the WHO or any individual countries released COVID-19 statistics divided on this basis?

Comment: Most countries share sex-distributed COVID-19 data. [538 has an article from a few days ago](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-are-more-men-than-women-dying-of-covid-19/) summarizing this data and providing some links

Answer (score 5):

The WHO has reported sex-distributed data - in their [89th COVID-19 situation report](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200418-sitrep-89-covid-19.pdf) published on April 13th, they released data on this topic aggregated from the then 747,546 cases reported by member states. Of these documented cases, 95.9% reported information on sex.

> **Distribution by age and sex of confirmed COVID-19 cases reported to the WHO case-based surveillance system
>   globally to date**
>
> A total of 716 570 CRFs (95.9%) reported information on age and sex. The sex ratio (male to female) among the
>   confirmed cases is 1.03:1, and the median age is 51 (interquartile range, IQR: 36-65) years.
>
> For males, the median age
>   is 52 (IQR 37-65) years, and for females 50 (IQR 35-64) years. The sex ratio varies significantly with age in all ranges
>   except 10-19 years. The largest sex ratios (male to female) are observed amongst the 0-9 year (1.16), 60-69 year
>   (1.27:1), and 70-79 year (1.34:1) age groups. Conversely, the lowest sex ratios (i.e. those showing more females than
>   males) are found in the 20-29 year (0.85:1) and 80 years and over (0.78:1) age groups.
>
> When cases reported
>   from the United States, Germany and Italy are excluded, the overall sex ratio changes to 0.95:1 (more females than
>   males amongst the cases), while there remains an excess of males in the 0-9, 60-69 and 70-79 year age groups.

[image]

So the WHO is reporting this data - and as its data comes from case reporting forms (CRFs) submitted by member states, it follows that individual countries are also reporting this data.

Comment: Here's another source from the UN that highlights the sex differences really clearly: https://data.unwomen.org/resources/covid-19-emerging-gender-data-and-why-it-matters